# Entity-framework code-first migrations NOCHECK constraint?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to alter tables in code-first migrations with nocheck constraints? I haven't found any way to do this except of getting SQL script via `Update-Database -Script` and modifying the sql statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try creating your own `MigrationSqlGenerator` and use it with migrations (you can set custom SQL generator in `DbMigrationsConfiguration`) - I think it should be enough to inherit `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` and add `NOCHECK` after adding foreign key = overriding `Generate(AddForeignKeyIperation operation)`.

Anyway using `NOCHECK` with EF is way to disaster. If you want to have database without checked constraints don't use EF because it will crash every time it reaches inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am very aware of the risks using NOCHECK, the related changes are quite minor and I believe nocheck is the only way to go in my case. I'll check out the MigrationSqlGenerator.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it for one-off occasions is to call the SQL for creating the FK manually, like so, from within your `Up()` method:

```
// AddForeignKey("dbo.EFElementGroupEntries", "ConstraintCode", "dbo.EFElementConstraints", "Code");
Sql(@"ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EFElementGroupEntries]  WITH NOCHECK 
        ADD CONSTRAINT[FK_dbo.EFElementGroupEntries_dbo.EFElementConstraints_ConstraintCode] FOREIGN KEY([ConstraintCode])
        REFERENCES[dbo].[EFElementConstraints]([Code])");
Sql(@"ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EFElementGroupEntries] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.EFElementGroupEntries_dbo.EFElementConstraints_ConstraintCode]");
```

Comment: Instead of just Sql() I have to use migrationBuilder.Sql() in case anyone else wonders where that gets defined

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to create a required foreign key but update-database fails due to existing data, just do it in two stages.  For example, suppose I want to add a foreign key for TEAM in a PLAYER class for a 1:m relationship where all players must be assigned to a team. Assuming all classes have integer identity primary keys...
 1. Add the usual two properties to PLAYER but use a nullable int for the foreign key.  ie:

```
    public int? TeamID { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
```

2. Add a migration and update the database.  All of the TeamID values will be null but you will be allowed to create the relationship.

   3. Next, fix your data so every player is assigned a valid TeamID.  If you are seeding player data, you will need to supply TeamID values there as well.
   4. Modify the PLAYER class so the int is no longer nullable:

      public int TeamID { get; set; }
   5. Add another migration and update the database again.  You should be good to go.

Comment: This answer seems the best to me but it has any drawbacks or risks?